# C# Dependency Injection with OOP Principles

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue with coding a basic dependency injection in C#,

To set things out I have an interface **IStorage** that contains IObject GetObject(int objID).

I then have two windows form:

- frmMain
- frmSearch

frmMain contains this code:

```
private readonly IStorage newStorage;


public frmMain()
{
newStorage = new Storage();
}
```

frmSearch contains this code:

```
public frmSearch(IStorage newStorage)
{
}
```

However I am receiving the error:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Application.IStorage' is less accessible than method 'Application.frmSearch.frmSearch(IStorage)'

A realise a fix for this is to make my interface public, but that forces me to make the Object Class public as well. I'm fairly new to OOP and this feels like bad coding practice to make all my classes and interfaces public(I could definitely be wrong) so I'm just not quite sure what to do here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I don't think that is a bad idea to mark `IStorage` as a public interface.

Comment: My problem with this is then I have to make all the classes that are referenced in any IStorage methods to public aswell, is this still ok?

Comment: The relevant code (`interface IStorage`) is not posted.

Comment: All IStorage contains is IObject GetObject(int ObjID)

Comment: So make `IObject` public as well.  Having some private implementations is understandable, but I don't see the harm in having public interfaces.

Comment: Cheers, setting all my interfaces to public solved the issue, not entirely sure what a public Interface has over a normal one.

Comment: @F17CH it allows it to be referenced outside of your assembly, and other potential programmers utilizing your assembly can then provide their own implementations of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that your classes/interfaces could be referenced outside the current assembly, then take a look at the internal access modifier:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

"A common use of internal access is in component-based development because it enables a group of components to cooperate in a private manner without being exposed to the rest of the application code. For example, a framework for building graphical user interfaces could provide Control and Form classes that cooperate by using members with internal access. Since these members are internal, they are not exposed to code that is using the framework.

**It is an error to reference a type or a member with internal access outside the assembly within which it was defined**."

Just keep in mind there's a hierarchy in encapsulation, so if a class (for example) has a public visibility, it's public methods can be used from outside the actual assembly. You have then to be careful to avoid having these methods to require parameter types with a lesser visibility, otherwise there would be an inconsistency. Luckily, Visual Studio warns the user about this.